# combine multiple nc files and events for a "for-loop"

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have 5 nc files which all includes dimensions and variables as:

nc1:
dimensions(sizes): altitude(801), frequency(2), n_event(421)

nc2:
dimensions(sizes): altitude(801), frequency(2), n_event(306)

nc3:
dimensions(sizes): altitude(801), frequency(2), n_event(527)

nc4:
dimensions(sizes): altitude(801), frequency(2), n_event(424)

nc5:
dimensions(sizes): altitude(801), frequency(2), n_event(487)

and looking inside the nc files:

```
variables(dimensions): float64 altitude(altitude), float64 frequency(frequency), float64 azimuth_of_occultation_plane(n_event), float64 bending_angle(n_event, altitude), float64 density(n_event, altitude), float64 dry_density(n_event, altitude), float64 dry_pressure(n_event, altitude), float32 dry_temperature(n_event, altitude), int64 event_id(n_event), float64 geoid_undulation(n_event), float64 geopotential_height(n_event, altitude), float64 impact_altitude(n_event, altitude), float64 incidence_angle_of_occultation_plane(n_event), float64 latitude(n_event), float32 latitude_trajectory(n_event, altitude), float64 longitude(n_event), float32 longitude_trajectory(n_event, altitude), float64 optimized_bending_angle(n_event, altitude), float64 pressure(n_event, altitude), int32 qc_bending_angle(n_event), int32 qc_dry_retrieval(n_event), int32 qc_physical_retrieval(n_event), int32 qc_refractivity(n_event), int32 qc_total(n_event), float64 radius_of_curvature(n_event), float64 raw_bending_angle(n_event, frequency, altitude), float64 refractivity(n_event, altitude), int32 set_rise_flag(n_event), float32 specific_humidity(n_event, altitude), float32 specific_humidity_raer(n_event, altitude), float32 specific_humidity_sigma(n_event, altitude), float64 surface_altitude(n_event), float32 temperature(n_event, altitude), float32 temperature_raer(n_event, altitude), float32 temperature_sigma(n_event, altitude), float64 time(n_event), int32 transmitter_id(n_event)
groups:
```

I don't know how I can combine all these 5 NC files together, as I am trying to have a for loop over all 421+306+527+424+487 events.

I am really new to python so I appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by first extracting the variables which I wanted by:

```
v1= nc1.variables['variable'][:]
v2= nc2.variables['variable'][:]
and ...
```

and as the v type was `"numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray"` I concatenate them by:

```
import numpy.ma as ma
v=ma.concatenate([v1,v2,...])
```